# How to get feedback on my quota increase request

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have filled th form to request a quota increase on Youtube API on July the 5th.
I have had no feedback since then.
If a Youtube API team member reads this post, please tell me how I can have some feedback on my request.

Thanks.

Comment: It can take a while to get a quota increase i have seen it take months.  You also need to remember that its summer time and even googlers take vacation.

Comment: I am aware it is not a Google support forum. But this is the only support solution offered by Youtube API team: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support?hl=fr
This was my solution of last resort to try to get some feedback. I tried many other channels before posting here.

Comment: Sorry you won't get any feedback on your application here.  You will have to wait